# Field isomorphic to a transcendental extension of itself

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $k$ be any field and $K:=k(X_1,X_2,\dots)$ be the field of rational functions over $k$ in countably many variables. Now $K$ has the interesting property that it is isomorphic to a transcendental extension of itself namely $K\cong K(X)$.

Are there any other examples of this phenomenon or is the following true?

> When $K$ is a field that is isomorphic to a transcendental extension of itself, then there is some field $k$ s.t. $K\cong k(X_1,X_2,\dots)$.

Comment: Follow-up question which is what I thought your question was at first: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2856060/if-k-cong-kx-then-must-k-be-a-field-of-rational-functions-in-infinitely-ma

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As written, no.

$\mathbb C$ is isomorphic to $\overline{\mathbb C(X)}$ which is a transcendental extension, but $\mathbb C$ is not isomorphic to anything of the form $k(X_1,X_2,\ldots)$ because the latter is not algebraically closed ($X_1$ does not have a square root, for example).

Comment: Why is $\mathbb{C}$ isomorphic to $\overline{\mathbb{C}(X)}$?

Comment: @Unit because they are both algebraically closed fields of the same characteristic and transcendence degree over their prime field. Any two such fields are isomorphic.

Comment: I see that by considering the theory consisting of the diagram of $K(X_1,X_2,\dots)$ and the  theory of $K$ we get a field $F$ which is an extension of $K(X_1,X_2,\dots)$ and elementarily equivalent to $K$. But how can i make $F$ actually isomorphic to $K$?

Comment: @Achilles: On further inspection, the argument I thought I had in mind for the last paragraph was terminally confused. All I'd get would be an $F$ elementarily extending $K$ such that $F$ is isomorphic to an extension of $F(X_1,X_1,\ldots)$, which is probably too far removed from the question to be interesting. I have removed the claim.